# Calculate $\mathbb{E}(X + Y)^2$ where $X \sim P(\lambda_{1})$ and $Y \sim P(\lambda_{2})$ are independent random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim P(\lambda_{1})$ and $Y \sim P(\lambda_{2})$ (they have Poisson's dispersion) be independent random variables such that 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X+Y>n) = 2$$.
Calculate: $\mathbb{E}(X + Y)^2$.

I know that now $X+Y \sim P(\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2})$. Now, I was wondering what to do with the sum written few lines up. It seems to me that maybe it would be easier to get some info using complement for each $n$ and then add all that together. So any hint regarding calculating sum helps.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(Z>n)$ is the expected value of $Z$ if it only takes values on the non-negative integers

Comment: Do you mean $E[(X+Y)^2]$ or $(E[X+Y])^{2}$?

Comment: @preferred_anon first option

Comment: And $\mathbb E[Z^2] = Var(Z)+(\mathbb E[Z])^2$ which makes this very easy for a Poisson distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: $X+Y$ has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda_1+\lambda_2$. The given condition is $\sum_n \sum_{k>n} e^{-\lambda} \frac {\lambda^{k}} {k!}=2$ where  $\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$. Interchange the order of summation to get $\sum_k ke^{-\lambda}\frac {\lambda^{k}} {k!}=2$. From this you get $\lambda=2$. Hence $X+Y$ is Poisson with parameter $2$ and $E(X+Y)^{2}=2^{2}+2=6$.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you interchange the order of summation so that you got $\sum_k ke^{-\lambda}\frac {\lambda^{k}} {k!}=2$? Thanks :)

Comment: $\sum_n \sum_{k>n} e^{-\lambda} \frac {\lambda^{k}} {k!}=\sum_{k\geq 0} k e^{-\lambda} \frac {\lambda^{k}} {k!}=\lambda \sum_{k\geq 0} ke^{-\lambda} \frac {\lambda^{k}} {k!}=\lambda$ where I used teh fact that $\sum_{n<k} 1=k$